# Javascript - Finding the distance between two numbers

Tags: javascript

Imagine the numbers 1 through 15

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

Now consider some value V from this list and another value D.

The question is, what is V - D.

But here's the catch: imagine that these values are a loop, not a linear count. In other words, "1" is right next to "15".

Comment: I didn't get it, can you describe it in other way ?

Comment: `myArray[v] - myArray[d]`?

Comment: Also, what did you mean by distance ? isn't it difference ?

Comment: "1" is right next to "15": sure, but this doesn't change the fact that 15-1=14... or maybe instead of V-D you mean the distance between V and D?

Comment: CodeGuy, do you want to know the "distance" between array indices? Like, you want to know that the array index with the value of `'a'` in the array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` is `-2` away from the array index with a value of `'c'`?

Answer (score 5):

Since you can wrap around, you can compare |V - D| with |15 - |V - D||. The smallest of these numbers will be the shortest distance between V and D.

Examples:

```
V    D    |V - D|    |15 - |V - D||    distance
-----------------------------------------------
1    1     0          15               0
1    15    14         1                1
2    1     1          14               1
2    15    13         2                2
```

Answer (score -1):

you could take the larger number then subtract the lesser number.

example in java

```
if(num1>num2){
num1-num2;
}else if(num2>num1){
num2-num1;
}
```

i dont know javascript but i know it is very similar